# Flutter: StatefulWidget call in loop after redirection

Tags: android, flutter, navigation, statefulwidget

In my widget witch is a **StatefulWidget**, my logic check a token and in error case, I navigate to my home page.

I'm waiting the widget finish to build by using this method:

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/');
});
```

But the problem is that even if I'm not focus on this widget anymore, he will still run in background and make a redirection in loop.

In my logic, I use setState **once** if my accesToken is expired. After that the widget rebuild and I check with the new token send my server, and if he is empty I redirect my user to the home page. I think the problem come from the setState.

So, is there a way to kill or dispose this widget after leaving ? Or maybe an other way to navigate ?

Answer (score 0):

So I'm gonna answer my own question, after several tests I found the solution.

I can break the loop by using **Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, '/'));** instead of **pushNamed**, it will pop the route off the navigator and so the widget will stop running on background when the parent is rebuild.